# Laravel - assign multiple videos to a course

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-9, laravel-10

I want to develope a website like udemy. My question is that how can I assign multiple videos to a course? Assume that a "course" contains 20 lessons/videos. How can I manage that? in Migration, Controller and Model.

Comment: Here's all the information you need about relationship between models, with examples and table structure. https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships I assume you'll want something simple like HasMany/BelongsTo

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use relationships, and you can find the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-polymorphic-relations).

Here's a sample code on how to do it:

**1.Create migrations and models.**

```
php artisan make:model Course -m
php artisan make:model Video -m
```

**2. Add columns to the tables and define the relationships.**

In the Course migration, add the following columns:

```
Schema::create('courses', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->text('description');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

In the Video migration, add the following columns:

```
Schema::create('videos', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->text('description');
    $table->string('video_url');
    $table->foreignId('course_id')->constrained();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

In the Course model, define the relationship to the Video model:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'description',
];

public function videos(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Video::class);
}
```

This sets up a one-to-many relationship between the Course and Video models, where the Course model has many Video models.

**3. Create a controller:**

```
php artisan make:controller CourseController
```

In the CourseController, define the index and show methods to display all courses and a single course, respectively.

```
public function index()
{
    return view('course.index', [
        'courses' => Course::all(),
    ]);
}

public function show(Course $course)
{
    return view('course.show', [
        'course' => $course,
    ]);
}
```

**4. Create views:**

Create an index.blade.php view that displays all courses:

```
<h1>Courses</h1>
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach ($courses as $course)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $course->id }}</td>
            <td><a href="{{ route('courses.show', $course) }}">{{ $course->name }}</a></td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Create a show.blade.php view that displays a single course and its associated videos:

```
<h1>{{ $course->name }}</h1>
<p>{{ $course->description }}</p>
@foreach ($course->videos as $video)

    <div>
        <h5>{{ $video->name }}</h5>
        <p>{{ $video->description }}</p>
        <a href="{{ $video->video_url }}">Watch</a>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

**5.Define routes:**

Lastly, you need to define routes for your CourseController methods. You can add the following code to your web.php file:

```
Route::get('/courses', [CourseController::class, 'index'])->name('courses.index');
Route::get('/courses/{course}', [CourseController::class, 'show'])->name('courses.show');
```

These routes map to the index and show methods in the CourseController.